# How to set z-index between 2 React Component with HashRouter

Tags: css, reactjs, z-index

Here is my code example - https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-jasper-n5rgb4?file=/src/Pages.js
u can see in video - https://vimeo.com/734975131

Comment: instead of making a route for notify ig you should make a component and conditionally render it

Comment: any idea? - https://youtu.be/FB3Mo_uPWjo

Comment: could you try `position:'absolute'` for notify parent div

Comment: position:'absolute' too not working. i don`t know why it`s not working